# patterns with nested for

Tags: python-3.x

How do i achieve the following pattern, if input is 3?

AA

BBAA

AABBAA

Furthest i can get was:

AA

BBBB

AAAAAA

I have tried the following:

```
#mod operator used to alternate patterns

pattern_size = int (input ("Input height : "))
for level in range (1, pattern_size +1):
    for x in range (level):
        # print AA if remainder != 0
        if level % 2 != 0:
            print ("AA", end = '')

        # print BB if remainder = 0
        if level % 2 == 0:
            print ("BB", end = '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is a homework, and you will get more if you will find the solution on your own.

Firstly, if you want to alternate `AA` and `BB` when printing on the same level, it must depend on `x` (because `x` changes when `level` does not change). Moreover, each level starts with a different pattern. This way you may want to test `(level + x) % 2 == 0` (choose the easy way of testing). If the boolean expression is true, print one pattern, else print the other.

Do not forget to `print()` without arguments after the `x` loop.

I prefer simpler usage of `range()` -- with a single argument. If `pattern_size` is 3, then the first loop can go through levels 0, 1, 2. However, the second `for` must loop at least once. Then you must go through `range(level + 1)`.